# What is the point of <buffer> in autocmds?

Tags: vimrc, buffers, autocmd

I know that the buffer is the window you're currently working in (or at least that's what I think it is), but why should I use buffer when scripting :autocmd?

For example:

```
autocmd FileType cpp,javascript,java,php :iabbrev <buffer> iff if ()<left>
```

will turn 'iff' into if () for a few file types.

I've tested it without buffer too and it still works. Is there any reason why I should include buffer?

Comment: the point is, do you want those abbreviations to be available globally to all buffers you edit or perhaps only to certain buffers of a particular filetype?

Comment: But shouldn't vim know that I only want the abbreviation to work for certain filetypes since I used FileType? If I didn't put <buffer> would the abbreviation still be global, even with the FileTypes put in?

Comment: Well, it is like executing a command only on the FileType autocommand, but afterwards it will affect every buffer, not just the one where the FileType autocommand fired. The `:iabbrev` command must have a way to know, whether the new abbreviation will be globally valid or only for your current buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The buffer is the *what* you're currently editing. It could be file, or not yet.

A window is the *where* it's edited.

Then, `<buffer>` is mandatory for your mappings/[abbreviations](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3aabbreviate%2d%3cbuffer%3e), command (with `-buffer` this time), menus (with a [plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/buffermenu.vim)) to exist only in the context of your current buffer. It's not directly related to `autocommands`. autocommands only define the when the definition is done.

For instance, you certainly don't want your `if` abbreviation to be expanded in the same fashion in C++, Python, Pascal, or in vim scripts language.

PS: your abbreviation suffer of several issues:

- it'll also be expanded in string or in comments
- it won't play well with bracketing plugins as it isn't `nore`
- it'll insert a trailing white space (search for `eatchar`, in Vim context)

Comment: So should I use -buffer instead of <buffer>? Also, is there any way to keep the abbreviation from activating in comments? Or do I have to just change the 'iff'. Thanks.

Comment: `-buffer` is for commands. `<buffer>` is for mappings and abbreviations. To avoid the issue about comments, you'll to test for the context. See for instance: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/ftplugin/c/c_snippets.vim#L78, but also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263471/apply-different-key-mappings-when-within-or-outside-a-comment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635642/remove-pressed-key-from-vim-input-buffer